# What are Floquet modes?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, experimental-physics, simulations, plasmon

When simulating a nanohole array for extraordinary optical transmission, I found that we have to use unit-cell boundary conditions. There is another concept to be understood which is Floquet modes. What are those, exactly? Which modes should I consider for transmission, reflection and diffraction?

Additional information: I am using CST studio for simulation.

Answer (score 1):

You might find it helpful to research [Floquet's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floquet_theory) first: it tells you what behavior to expect in linear differential equations with co-efficients which are periodic functions of the independent variable. These naturally arise in periodic structures. So you don't get modes in the usual sense found in waveguide theory, *i.e.* you don't get solutions which propagate along the axis of symmetry in a translationally-invariant structure by simple phase delays with uniform phase velocity as they go.

But you do get solutions which propagate by phase delay *together with* multiplication by a periodic function of the translation co-ordinate. These "quasi" modes are the Floquet modes.